# Add items to combo box in edit mode Openoffice Base

Tags: openoffice-base

I am trying to add a couple of options to a combobox in openoffice base. The combobox will only ever have two options that can be selected so it's rediculous to have a table for specifying the items in the list. How do I add the options to the combobox in edit mode? I know that in visual studio I can achieve this by simply creating a combobox control and opening the properties, scrolling to the "list content" property and adding typing in each item, separated by a line break. How can I do this in openoffice base? After scouring the internet, I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Comment: What engine are you using?  For example the default HSQLDB 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the properties of a combo box.  In the Data tab for `Type of list contents`, specify `SQL [Native]`.  For `List content`, specify the following query:

```
SELECT 'No' FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 'Yes' FROM DUAL
```

That is if the engine is Oracle.  For MySQL, only this is needed:

```
SELECT 'Yes' UNION SELECT 'No';
```

For the embedded HSQLDB engine, version 1.8 requires a special table to be created.[1]  Create a table called `MY_DUMMY` with only one column and one row.  This will behave like Oracle's [DUAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table) table.  Then specify the query like this:

```
SELECT 'No' FROM MY_DUMMY UNION SELECT 'Yes' FROM MY_DUMMY
```

[1] In newer versions of HSQLDB, it is possible to use [(VALUES(0))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562323/5100564) as a dummy table, but LO uses the older version by default.

[2] [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) combines two SELECT statements.

**EDIT**:

Here are step by step instructions using Apache OpenOffice 4.1.2.  All tables and fields are upper case to make SQL easier.

1. In OpenOffice, go to `File -> New -> Database`.
2. Radio `Create a new database`.[3]  Next.
3. `No, do not register the database.`
4. `Finish`.  Save the file somewhere.
5. `Create Table in Design View`.
6. Field Name: `ID`. Field Type: `Integer [ INTEGER ]`.
7. Right-click to the left of `ID` and specify `Primary key`.
8. Save as `MY_DUMMY` and then close the table.
9. `Create Table in Design View`.
10. Again create an `ID` field as primary key.
11. Also create a field called `VALUE` as type `Text [ VARCHAR ]`.
12. Save as `MY_TABLE1` and close.
13. Double-click on table `MY_DUMMY` and add one record with value `0`.
14. Press enter to save the record, then close the table.
15. Double-click on table `MY_TABLE1` and add two records with `ID` of `0` and `1`.
16. Set the `VALUE` field to `No` for both records and close the table.
17. In the `Forms` area, `Use Wizard to Create Form...`
18. `Tables or queries`: `Table: MY_TABLE1`.
19. Click `>>` to move `ID` and `VALUE` to the right side.
20. Press `Finish`, then close the form.
21. Right-click on the `MY_TABLE1` form and choose `Edit`.
22. With the Combo Box tool, drag a large square to create the combo box.
23. Press `Cancel` to close the wizard.
24. Right-click on the combo box and choose `Control`.
25. In the `Data` tab, for `Data field`, specify `VALUE`.
26. For `Type of list contents`, specify `Sql [Native]`.
27. For `List content`, specify `SELECT 'No' FROM MY_DUMMY UNION SELECT 'Yes' FROM MY_DUMMY`.
28. Save and close the form.
29. Double-click to open the form.
30. In the combo box, click `Yes`.
31. At the top of the combo box, click to the right of `Yes` to move the cursor there.
32. Press `Enter` to accept the value of the combo box.

Now you should see the value in the table change to `Yes`.

[3]   This option uses an embedded database, which is [not recommended](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#So_why_should_I_avoid_.27embedded_databases.27.3F) for production environments, only for testing and development.  The engine is [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that out tomorrow. But what is "union" and "dual". I'm new to open office and haven't worked with SQL in a long time so I don't entirely understand

Comment: To see what they do, try it at an SQL prompt or in LO Base go to `Tools -> SQL`.  I also added links above that explains those terms.

Comment: This is not working. only the HSQLDB method does not produce an error, however it does not add anything to the combobox. Can you please explain further? Does it matter what I call the column name or the datatype?

Comment: Please explain (VALUES(0)). The post you linked to doesn't explain anything about it.

Comment: I added step by step instructions.  See if you can get them to work.  If not, let me know if there is a particular step that is unclear.